# ¿Cómo puedo contar los productos comprados por un usuario de woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy intentando contar cuántos productos ha creado un usuario logeado.

Mi intención es crear un contador para que, una vez alcanzado un número determinado de posts creados por el usuario, éste ya no pueda seguir creando.

Para esto tengo la siguiente función:

```php
function dime_cuantos_ha_comprado($lleva_comprados) {

    $el_contador = $lleva_comprados; // a $lleva_comprados le paso el valor "10"

    // Obtenemos todos los pedidos del cliente
    $pedidos = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
        'post_status' => array( 'wc-processing', 'wc-completed' )
    ) );

    // Del conjunto de pedidos, exploro uno por uno
    foreach ($pedidos as $pedido)
    {
        // Obtengo el primer elemento del pedido
        $orden = wc_get_order( $pedido );
        // De ese elemento, se hace el desglose de los item que contiene
        $items_de_la_orden = $orden->get_items();

        // Reviso entre los items para encontrar el ID de producto
        foreach ( $items_de_la_orden as $item ) {

            $id_del_producto = $item->get_product_id();

            // Reviso si este id de producto coincide con los que me interesan
            if ( $id_del_producto == '1' ):
                $el_contador = $el_contador + 5;
            elseif ( $id_del_producto == '2' ):
                $el_contador = $el_contador + 10;
            elseif ( $id_del_producto == '3' ):
                $el_contador = $el_contador + 25;
            endif;

        } // foreach de lineas de pedido
    }  // foreach de cada pedido

    $el_contador = $el_contador - 10; // Le descuento los "10" con los que inicié
    $el_return = '';
    if( $el_contador == 0 ):
        $el_return = 'Dio 0';
    elseif( $el_contador == 10 ):
        $el_return = 'No se modificó';
    else:
        $el_return = $el_contador;
    endif;
}
```

El problema que tengo es que la función no me devuelve **ningún valor** de **$el_return**

Ya he probado colocar la función en mi archivo de funciones personalizadas, y en el functions.php, utilizando el hook

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_dashboard', 'dime_cuantos_ha_comprado', 10 );
```

También he probado llamarla declarándola directamente en la plantilla, incluyendo el *return* y también quitándolo.

Muchas gracias por su apoyo

Comment: Como te comenté o otra pregunta. Tienes que tener un hook, un shortcode u otra forma de invocar la función desde el lugar donde necesites mostrar los datos que devuelve la función. Si no invocas la función de alguna forma no podrás ver lo que ésta devuelve. Explica por favor cómo invocas la función, si con un hook, un shortcode u otra forma. Gracias.